# How to elegantly send/receive a large C struct using Python?

Tags: python, c, sockets, struct, python-3.x

I have started to write a Python 3.x client application. The server application exists already and is written in C. The server provides a C header file with the definition of two structures used to send and receive data via UDP (I am using Python's `socket` module).
The problem is that the C structures are quite large (around 200 elements each). If I use Python's `struct` module to pack/unpack the data, a not-so-elegant solution would be packing/unpacking the 200 elements manually, like:

```
struct.pack('H...I', data1, ..., data200)
```

Furthermore, I want to be able to access the received/sent elements in Python using a C-like syntax. For example, if I do in the C server side

```
send.data.pos = pos;
```

it would be nice (most natural) if I can access the `pos` variable in the Python client side like this:

```
pos = recv.data.pos
```

Note that the question is *not* how to automatically write the structure in Python from the header file, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050318/extract-the-fields-of-a-c-struct) thread (I have no problem in writing each structure field one by one in Python), but rather what would be the best way to organise the data in Python (e.g. in classes, using dictionaries, etc.) that will allow me to exploit Python features and made the code simpler and the data easy to access (I'd rather use only Python standard modules, no external software). What would be the most elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Why aren't you simply building a class for the message?  Why ask?  What stops you from writing a class?

Comment: Have you looked at Cython? http://cython.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -- works on 2.7 and 3.2.

Script:

```
import struct, collections

class CStruct(object):

    def __init__(self, typename, format_defn, lead_char="!"):
        self.names = []
        fmts = [lead_char]
        for line in format_defn.splitlines():
            name, fmt = line.split()
            self.names.append(name)
            fmts.append(fmt)
        self.formatstr = ''.join(fmts)
        self.struct = struct.Struct(self.formatstr)
        self.named_tuple_class = collections.namedtuple(typename, self.names)

    def object_from_bytes(self, byte_str):
        atuple = self.struct.unpack(byte_str)
        return self.named_tuple_class._make(atuple)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # do this once
    pkt_def = """\
        u1 B
        u2 H
        u4 I"""
    cs = CStruct("Packet1", pkt_def)
    # do this once per incoming packet
    o = cs.object_from_bytes(b"\xF1\x00\xF2\x00\x00\x00\xF4")
    print(o)
    print(o.u4)
```

Output:

```
Packet1(u1=241, u2=242, u4=244)
244
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a class that has member functions to pack/unpack the data to/from class attributes, using `struct.pack` etc.

I would suggest looking into [Construct](http://construct.wikispaces.com/). But I don't think it has been ported to Python 3.x yet. Construct has been on hiatus for some time, but recently been picked up by a new developer, so perhaps it could support Python 3.x soon.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [dpkt](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/) as a simple way of accessing the packet data.  Take a look [here](http://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2008/10/15/dpkt-tutorial-2-parsing-a-pcap-file/) for usage examples.  For a simple example:

```
class Foo(dpkt.Packet):
    __hdr__ = (('type', 'B', 0),
               ('size', 'B', 0))

data = get_udp_message()
foo = Foo(data)
if foo.size != len(data):
    print "Bad size in header"
if foo.type == 3:
    parse_payload(foo.data)
```