# how to send structure as parameter in python

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

I am using boost python for  interoperability between C++ and the Python . i have enum and structure in c++ and have function in c++ that can take these structure as a parameter. and  i am able to access this function in python by using boost python but i don't know how to send structure as parameter in python. Set is function in c++ that can get structure as parameter.so in python how can i send this structure as a parameter . i am able to get this function in python but not able to send send structure as parameter. thanks for the help.

structure in c++ is as follow:

```
enum days
{
  friday,
  saturday
};
struct example
 {
    days m_day;
    std: string m_value;
 };

Class Base
 {
   public:
   void Set(example& Result) = 0;
  }
class Derived
{
  public:
  void Set(example& Result) 
  {
    Result.m_day = friday;
   }
```

Comment: no i want to send structure as pyrameter from python to c++.

Comment: Maybe this could help you ? [send-receive-cstruct-using-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037555/how-to-elegantly-send-receive-a-large-c-struct-using-python)

Comment: how can i send empty structure from python that it can assess the Structurevalue of c++?not able to send Structure from python

Comment: Expose the enum and struct via [`boost::python::enum`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/enum.html) and [`boost::python::class_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec).  Boost.Python will handle converting to-and-from the struct and the associated Python types.

Comment: Problem is that how can i send empty structure from python that it can  access the structure in c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to expose structure example like this and then create a variable of this structure in python and send this variable as argument.

```
Class_<example> (“example”)
.def_readwrite(“m_day” , & example:: day)
.def_readwrite(“m_value” , & example:: m_value)
;
```

Hope this will help..